# Pullback of canonical divisor along a generically finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism between smooth projective varieties of the same dimension over $\mathbb C$. Then we have the following equality on canonical divisors
$$K_X \cong f^* K_Y + R$$
where $R$ is an effective divisor supported on the ramification locus. In particular, we have

> if $h^0(K_Y)\neq 0$, then $h^0(K_X)\neq 0$.

And my question is

> if we generalize the condition "finite morphism" to "generically finite morphism", does this implication still hold?

At first I expect some formula like
$$K_X \cong f^* K_Y + R +E$$
to be true, where $E$ is some effective divisor, and this will lead to what I want. But then I realized that this is not likely to be true when the exceptional fibers (i.e. those with positive dimension) do not form a divisor. Then I do not know how to approach this in general. Maybe this is just false but could anyone provide a counter-example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For such morphisms, you have a natural inclusion of line bundles $f^*K_Y\subset K_X$ (by pulling back forms) and thus $K_X=f^*K_Y+E$ for some effective divisor $E$.

Comment: @Mohan Aha! Thank you very much! (and I am so stupid...)